# Calculate total number of entries from a table in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a perfect example, but i have to mentioned dates and state manually in the below example, how to select all available dates and state in the DB table.

```
SELECT state,
       SUM( if( date='2013-10-01', 1, 0) ) `2013-10-01`,
       SUM( if( date='2013-10-02', 1, 0) ) `2013-10-02`, 
       SUM( if( date='2013-10-03', 1, 0) ) `2013-10-03`
       --  .........   
       --  .........  
       --  .........  
FROM `table`
GROUP BY state;

| STATE | 2013-10-01 | 2013-10-02 | 2013-10-03 |
|-------|------------|------------|------------|
|    CO |          4 |          2 |          3 |
|    NY |          3 |          1 |          0 |
|    TX |          1 |          0 |          4 |


SELECT `date`,
       SUM( CASE state WHEN 'NY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) `NY`,
       SUM( CASE state WHEN 'CO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) `CO`,
       SUM( CASE state WHEN 'TX' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) `TX`
       --  .........  
       --  .........  
       --  .........  
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`

|                           DATE | NY | CO | TX |
|--------------------------------|----|----|----|
| October, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  3 |  4 |  1 |
| October, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  1 |  2 |  0 |
| October, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  0 |  3 |  4 |
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I want to integrate this into phpcode

Comment: Is this about how to execute the queries you posted in php or about writing the queries because they don't return what you want them to return?

Comment: the query is return what i want to return. but i have to mentioned dates and states here manually. for example : SUM( if( date='2013-10-01', 1, 0) ) `2013-10-01`,
       SUM( if( date='2013-10-02', 1, 0) ) `2013-10-02`, 
       SUM( if( date='2013-10-03', 1, 0) ) `2013-10-03`

Comment: but i want whatever dates available and whatever states available in the table will return.

Comment: @user3438532 . . . This requires dynamic SQL (use of a `prepare`) statement.  It cannot be done automatically through a simple SQL statement.